# Rails and Devise giving Error for Signup Page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I've googled and SOed for the answer to this, so even though this question is similar to others posed already, please know I have tried all of the answers posted here already.

I've been following a tutorial to set up a Rails site with users etc. I'm at the stage where I tried to use Devise to generate a user db.

I get this error when I try to access the signup page:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Devise::RegistrationsController#new
```

The advice I have found is to use `rake db:migrate` in order to fix the db.

This gives me the following error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: email: ALTER TABLE "installs" ADD "email" varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL/ruby/testapp/omrails/db/migrate/20130510151217_add_devise_to_installs.rb:5:in `block in up'
/ruby/testapp/omrails/db/migrate/20130510151217_add_devise_to_installs.rb:3:in `up'
/Users/BWS/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/Users/BWS/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

The interwebs then leads me to believe that deleting my development.sqlite3 and rerunning `rake db:migrate` will solve my problem, however this leads to:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: email: ALTER TABLE "installs" ADD "email" varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL/ruby/testapp/omrails/db/migrate/20130510151217_add_devise_to_installs.rb:5:in `block in up'
```

again.

[Possibly Related]
I also receive the following message when I do just about anything with rails:

```
/Users/BWS/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/yaml.rb:56:in `<top (required)>':
It seems your ruby installation is missing psych (for YAML output).
To eliminate this warning, please install libyaml and reinstall your ruby.
```

But all of the suggested advice online has yet to fix the issue.

Sorry for the long post, trying to be very thorough, any advice would be appreciated.

**Update:**

So I can't get it to generate a new schema (I trashed the DB folder several times to try different things) but here is one of the deleted ones:

```
# encoding: UTF-8
# This file is auto-generated from the current state of the database. Instead
# of editing this file, please use the migrations feature of Active Record to
# incrementally modify your database, and then regenerate this schema definition.
#
# Note that this schema.rb definition is the authoritative source for your
# database schema. If you need to create the application database on another
# system, you should be using db:schema:load, not running all the migrations
# from scratch. The latter is a flawed and unsustainable approach (the more migrations
# you'll amass, the slower it'll run and the greater likelihood for issues).
#
# It's strongly recommended to check this file into your version control system.

ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 0) do

end
```

Comment: What version of rails do you use? Also you should reinstall ruby, to remove the YAML warning...

Comment: I just reinstalled. I'm 3.2.13 for rails and 1.9.3 for Ruby. I just reinstalled and the YAML warning is alive and well :/

Comment: Have you tried to install libyaml? If you use brew you could do `brew install libyaml`

Comment: brew install libyaml leads to Warning: libyaml-0.1.4 already installed, it's just not linked

How do I link?

Comment: OK so I uninstalled and reinstalled, still get the error:  missing psych (for YAML output) and the Not Linked error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you have two migrations that both adds an email field to `installs`. You have to look through all you migration files and see if this is true. There are three ways to add a email field to a table, so look for more then one of these:

```
#1
create_table "installs" do |t|
  t.string :email

#2
change_table "installs" do |t|
  t.string :email

#3
add_column :installs, :email, :string
```

Comment: I reinstalled rails, deleted all the migrations, now there is only one migration (after running 'sudo rails generate devise' User again), but I still get the ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Devise::RegistrationsController#new
 and Could not find table 'users'
 errors when I go to the signup page. Have I missed something?

Comment: Have you remembered to drop/delete your database, and run `rake db:migrate` after deleting and recreating all migrations?

Comment: this leads to: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: users. Sorry to be so frustrating, I just don't get why nothing is working.

Comment: You should checkout http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html to learn more about migrations. A migration makes changes to the database like creating tables, changing columns and so forth. You should have a migration for each of your models that creates the corresponding table. Devise have a generator to create the right migration for the devise user. If you use devise on `users` then you should run `rails generate devise User`, and then `rake db:migrate`

Comment: Try to post your `schema.rb` file here. Otherwise join this room and i can help you out :) http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/29755/rails-migration

Answer (score 4):

Some versions of Devise create migrations without the .rb extension. When I had the same error as you I navigated back to the 'migrate' folder and sure enough the generated migration lacked the extension. Adding .rb and then running $ rake db:migrate fixed this issue for me.

Comment: That worked for me after seeing this error: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Devise::RegistrationsController#new